# Creating a subset dataset: filter function returned a series but returned scalar bool

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to create a subset df with all absolute value of ['Invoice Amount'] > 1000 filtered out.

```
abs_filter = lambda subset: subset['Invoice Amount'].abs() < 1000
filter_df2 = df.groupby(
              ['year', 'month','Unit','Name']).filter(lambda grp: abs_filter(grp))
filter_df2
```

I keep getting error: filter function returned a series but expected a scalar bool. New to python and pandas and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not filter and then group by? It is better

```
df[df['Invoice Amount'].abs() < 1000].groupby(['year', 'month','Unit','Name'])
```

If you filter after groupby, it's a filter for the groups, not the data. Hence, it requires True or False(scalar bool) value for each group.

Going by your question, why even groupby if you just need a filtered subset, like,

```
df[df['Invoice Amount'].abs() < 1000, ['year', 'month','Unit','Name']]
```

Comment: Did I answer your question @Ryan Gold?

Answer (score 0):

To create a subset, you can try the following -

```
df_subset = df[df['Invoice Amount'].abs() < 1000]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.